# CSS - align-items: center not centering items

Tags: html, css

I have 4 elements inside 1 element like so:

```
<div class="gt-columns gt-columns-center">

<div class="gt-col"></div>
<div class="gt-col"></div>
<div class="gt-col"></div>
<div class="gt-col"></div>

</div>
```

I am trying to center the 4 gt-col inside the gt-columns. I have align-items set to center but nothing is centering. What am I doing wrong? Here is my CSS:

```
.gt-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -15px -30px;
}

.gt-columns.gt-columns-center {
    align-items: center;
}

.gt-col {
    width: 14.28571428571429%;
}
```

Comment: `flex` is the wrong `display` to use here. You should use `display: grid`.

Comment: @VXp I just had a baby, sorry for the little time I had to get something done I didn't properly ask my question, but did however get my point across on what Im trying to accomplish.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol my 4 gt-col are now stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to center your flex-children *horizontally*, you need to use:

```
justify-content: center;
```

If you wish to center your flex-children *vertically*, you need to use:

```
align-items: center;
```

You may of course use both.

---

**N.B.** If you apply `flex-direction: column;` then

- `justify-content: center;` will now apply to the vertical axis
- `align-items: center;` will now apply to the horizontal access

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.gt-columns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 18px;
}

.gt-columns.column {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.gt-col {
    width: 14.3%;
    height: 36px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="gt-columns gt-columns-center">
  <div class="gt-col"></div>
  <div class="gt-col"></div>
  <div class="gt-col"></div>
  <div class="gt-col"></div>
</div>

<div class="gt-columns gt-columns-center column">
  <div class="gt-col"></div>
  <div class="gt-col"></div>
  <div class="gt-col"></div>
  <div class="gt-col"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the flexbox parent container's primary axis is horizontal and controlled by the `justify-content` property. The secondary axis is vertical and will be controlled by `align-items`. You can flip this around with `flex-direction` if you like. You have to **apply these to the parent container** (`.gt-columns` for you).

Now `align-items` will sometimes not appear to do anything. If the parent container collapses to the size of the children (which it's doing in your case), there isn't anything to center: the container and items have the same height.

You didn't use `justif-content` so the horziontal axis has been ignored. I revised your code:

```
.gt-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -15px -30px;
}

.gt-columns.gt-columns-center {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the bold on **APPLY THESE TO THE PARENT CONTAINER**. I had a `<nav><ul><li>` structure, and I was applying the property to `<nav>`, while I should have been applying it to `<ul>`!